# Folium создание круглых маркеров

Tags: html, css, python

Вопрос глупый, однако не могу понять почему не выходит создать круглый маркер нужного цвета
Мой код:

```
import folium
map = folium.Map(location=[my_latitude, my_longitude], zoom_start=12)
map.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt, ln], radius=6, popup='text', color='grey', fillColor='red', fill=True, fill_opacity=0.7))
map.save('map.html')
```

В итоге создается круглый маркер полностью серого цвета, хотя должен быть с красной заливкой внутри. От перемены мест аргументов ничего не меняется, читал документацию здесь: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#circlemarker
аргументы указаны правильно
Подскажите, в чем моя проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Судя по исходникам, параметр должен называться `fill_color`](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/folium/vector_layers.py#L49):

```
def path_options(line=False, radius=False, **kwargs):
    """
    ...
    skipped
    ...
    fill_color: str, default to `color` (fillColor)
        Fill color. Defaults to the value of the color option.
    ...
```

Соответственно, попробуйте заменить параметр `fillColor='red'` на `fill_color='red'`.

Comment: огромное спасибо, помогло
странно, что в исходниках и документации все разное